# How to smooth rgl plot? Plot is extremely stuttering,

Tags: r, rgl

This very simple plot is stucking when dragging, rotating, etc. It's not slow, but the extend is changing making it really difficult to follow the data. 
It's because of the axis labels which are repositioned during the interaction. But why is this also if I set axis = FALSE? It's still jumping around... Any ideas?

```
library(rgl)

# has glitches during rotation, etc.
xyz = rbind(
  c(696640.9, 211180.6, 1125.691),
  c(696640.9, 211180.5, 1125.696),
  c(696640.9, 211180.1, 1125.725),
  c(696641.1, 211179.8, 1125.813)
)
plot3d(xyz, type="p", size=10)

# runs smoothly
xyz = rbind(
  c(6, 2, 1),
  c(9, 5, 6),
  c(4, 1, 5),
  c(1, 8, 3)
)
plot3d(xyz, type="p", size=10)
```

How can I fix this 'bug'? Thanks alot.

Also, due to the jumping, the positioning of the data itself seem to be corrupted. For example, the green line is touching the red line datawise. But that's not consistant for all viewing angles. [image]

**EDIT**

The suggested answer using `scale()` is fixing the issue for `plot3d()` but is not solving the issue for me. I'm adding more data to the plot with `points3d()`, `segments3d()` and `abcline3d()` which are then not well placed. Even if I use `scale()` also on the data added by these functions.

Comment: Not a fix really, but a possible workaround might be to scale your data:  `plot3d(scale(xyz), type="p", size=10)`, you'd have to think about how to construct axes if you don't like what that produces.

Comment: It looks like a real bug: I can confirm it happens on linux, in case it is relevant (recent Ubuntu 64 bits)

Comment: rgl uses single precision in various places.  This was necessary when it was first written 15 years ago, but might not be nowadays.  Single precision only gives about 6-7 digit accuracy, so you're seeing rounding error.  Following Jota's suggestion is the best workaround.

Comment: hm, ok. Is there a library more up to date? In this case, I can't use scale() since I'm adding data later to the plot with abcline3d().

Comment: Scale (or just centre) your data before you start, and scale everything.  `rgl` isn't the only thing that will suffer because your data is so badly scaled, it's just particularly sensitive to bad data storage.